# Resilient Population Card in Pandemic

Tags: pandemic

Once a city card is removed from the infection deck, do you still place infection cubes on that city?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can still place infection cubes in that city if they would be placed there through other methods. You just won't draw that card anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though the only reason for placing cubes in that city is an outbreak in an adjacent city.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).